# View setVisibility with GestureDetector in Android

Tags: java, android, gesturedetector

I have a GestureListener with a view. I want to change view visibility based on the GestureListener results. On double tap show the view, on single tap hide it. And I want to show the vie when I'll hold my finger on the display (snapchat like feature).

```
mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
    mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Here's my gesture listeners.. On double tap it'll show my view but it keeps the view visible

```
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapUp: " + event.toString());
    text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: " + event.toString());
    text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I added

ImageView imgView11 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagek11d);

just before imgView11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

and before imgView11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);